# feature selection in wrapper method and information filtering?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, pattern-recognition, feature-selection

I see one example in old-mid exam from well-known person `Tom Mitchell`, as follows:

> Consider learning a classiﬁer in a situation with 1000 features total.
>   50 of them are truly informative about class. Another 50 features are
>   direct copies of the ﬁrst 50 features. The ﬁnal 900 features are not
>   informative. Assume there is enough data to reliably assess how useful
>   features are, and the feature selection methods are using good
>   thresholds.

```
How many features will be selected by mutual information ﬁltering?
```

Solution: 100

```
How many features will be selected by a wrapper method?
```

solution: 50

My challenge is how these solution is achieved? I do lots of try, but couldn't understand the idea behind this.

Answer (score 7):

```
How many features will be selected by mutual information ﬁltering?
```

Mutual information feature-selection evaluates the candidacy of each feature **independently**. Since there are essentially 100 features that are truly informative, we will ended up with 100 features by mutual information filtering.

```
How many features will be selected by a wrapper method?
```

A wrapper method evaluates a subset of features thus it takes the **interactions** between features into account. Since 50 features are direct copies of the other 50 features, the wrapper method is able to find out that **conditioned on** the first 50 features, the second set of 50 features is not adding any **extra information** at all. We ended up with 50 features after filtering. Suppose the first set of 50 features are `A1, A2, ..., A50` and the copy of the 50 features are `C1, C2, ..., C50`. The final result of selected features might look like:

```
A1, C2, A3, A4, C5, C6, ..., A48, A49, C50.
```

Thus each **unique** feature should have only one occurrence (either from the feature set of `A` or from the feature set of `C`).

Answer (score -1):

**How many features will be selected by mutual information filtering?**

If we go by the question description, we should only have 50 features selected. But this filtering is based on correlation with the variable to predict. And, also one the *major drawbacks* of Mutual Information Filtering is, **they tend to select redundant variables because they does not consider the relationships between variables.**

**How many features will be selected by a wrapper method?**

Consider it as a Heuristic Search approach of space of all possible feature subsets. By definition, **"A wrapper method evaluates a subset of features thus it takes the interactions between features into account."**

**Example:**  Hill Climbing , i.e. keep adding features one at a time until no further improvement can be achieved.

Since we have 50 feature which have the most information, other 50 a copy of the former and 900 feature are or no use. Therefore, we get only 50 features.